# How to make Concurrency utilities (JSR 236) work in plain non-EE Tomcat 8?

Tags: java, tomcat, executorservice, java-ee-7, apache-tomee

My technical stack includes

- [Tomcat 8.5.47](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi) (plain, not EE)
- [Weld 2.4.8.Final](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.weld.servlet/weld-servlet/2.4.8.Final) (as a reference implementation of CDI 1.2)

To be able to use [`ManagedExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedExecutorService.html) and manage threads more wisely and in a safer manner, I would like to include this dependency

- [`org.glassfis:javax.enterprise.concurrent`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.enterprise.concurrent) (as a reference implementation of [JSR 236 [Concurrency Utilities]](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=236))

I tried to inject the bean in different ways and into differently-scoped beans (view-, session-, application-based).

```
  @Inject
  private javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedExecutorService service;
```

```
  @Resource
  private javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedExecutorService service;
```

```
  @Resource(lookup="java:comp/DefaultManagedExecutorService")
  private javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedExecutorService service;
```

Nothing seems to work and the exception goes

> ```
> java.lang.RuntimeException:
>     Error looking up java:comp/env/.../ManagedExecutorService in JNDI
> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:
>     Name [.../ManagedExecutorService] is not bound in this Context.
> ```

It might be due to improper bean registration. Because I found none. I scanned the whole classpath and couldn't find anything that defines `ManagedExecutorService` or any of its implementations somewhere.

I tried to register it by myself in the `context.xml` to no avail. I used [this TomEE tutorial](https://tomee.apache.org/admin/configuration/resources.html) (naively) assuming that configuration for my non-EE Tomcat would be the same.

```
<Resource name="ManagedExecutorService"
          type="javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedExecutorService" />
```

```
<Resource id="ManagedExecutorService"
          type="javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedExecutorService" />
```

Apparently, it's not.

My questions are

1. Is it possible to set up Concurrency Utilities on a non-EE server, Tomcat 8.5 in particular?
2. If so, what am I missing here?

I can't switch to any JavaEE application server.
I can't upgrade the listed dependencies.

**Related:**

- [Java EE specification and multi threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212255/java-ee-specification-and-multi-threading/19404307#19404307)
- [Is it safe to manually start a new thread in Java EE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149919/is-it-safe-to-manually-start-a-new-thread-in-java-ee)
- [Why am I getting a WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46529534/why-am-i-getting-a-weld-001303-no-active-contexts-for-scope-type-javax-enterpri)

Comment: So "@Inject" will definitely not work in Tomcat. Those is a JavaEE annotation, and Tomcat simply ignores it. Tomcat only implements the JSP and Servlet parts of JavaEE. You would need to use Apache TomEE which does work quite nicely :)

Comment: You would need to add the Glassfish implementation to the `tomcat/lib` directory, then in the `server.xml`, initialize an instance of it. Then, in a servlet, or filter, you can use the `@Resource` annotation to inject it (you shouldn't need to qualify the name if it's the only one)

Comment: If you're using Weld and Tomcat, you really ought to switch to TomEE. You're currently trying to hand-assemble a JavaEE server actually, and TomEE is a community that has done all the footwork for you.

Comment: @JonathanS.Fisher Thanks, I really appreciate you responded to my comments under your answer there. Actually, I made CDI work in plain Tomcat, and I successfully moved all my `@ManagedBean`s to CDI beans (e.g. `@Named` + `@SessionScoped`)

Comment: @JonathanS.Fisher I understand that I am basically assembling TomEE (a more lightweight and with fewer dependencies version). I don't need 80% of what TomEE is offering. And I suppose moving a big project from Tomcat to TomEE might be problematic.

Comment: @JonathanS.Fisher I am working on a small feature that requires spawning threads from CDI components. I could implement my own mechanism, but why should I if there is already a JSR and independent (I hope so - I started doubting this part) reference implementation for it?

Comment: Can I ask what the goal is?  You say that you don't need 80% of what is in TomEE but it's unclear what you do need.  If you're looking for a micro-service environment then something like [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/) may be an option.  Wildfly isn't bad but certainly wouldn't be used for something like an AWS Lambda.  So, again, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @stdunbar I want to make as little changes as possible (configuration-wise, and dependency-wise) and to have some EE features work in plain Tomcat (CDI [done] and Concurrency Management in CDI context [that's what the question is about]). It's not an architecture question.